# How to merge group by list and sum no-key value

Tags: c#, .net

For example i have a grouped by list:

```
List<Cl> list = new List<Cl>()
        {
            new Cl() { vi = 1, vs = "q", am = 20 },
            new Cl() { vi = 1, vs = "w", am = 30 },
            new Cl() { vi = 2, vs = "w", am = 40 },
            new Cl() { vi = 1, vs = "q", am = 50 }
        };
groups = list.GroupBy(b => new { b.vi, b.vs }).ToList();
```

And i want to get merged list with summing am field:

```
Key       am
[1, "q"] [70] 
[1, "w"] [30] 
[2, "w"] [40]
```

Is it possible to realize it without Dictionaries or KeyValuePair?

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `GroupBy()`, then `Sum()` up the `am` values of each group

```
List<Cl> groups = list.GroupBy(b => new { b.vi, b.vs })
                      .Select(x => new Cl() { vi = x.Key.vi,
                                              vs = x.Key.vs, 
                                              am = x.Sum(y => y.am) }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
class Key
{
    public int Vi { get; set; }
    public string Vs { get; set; }

    public Key(int vi, string vs)
    {
        Vi = vi;
        Vs = vs;
    }
}

var result = groups = list.GroupBy(b => new { b.vi, b.vs })
                          .Select(gr=> new { Key = Key(gr.vi,gr.vs)
                                           , Value = gr.Sum(x=>x.am)})
                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(b => new { b.vi, b.vs })
                 .Select(g => new { g.Key, am = g.Sum(s => s.am)})
                 .ToList();
```